# mupdf cannot display some pdf files

Tags: mupdf

When attempting to open a pdf using mupdf.exe the following error is displayed:

Please wait...

If this message is not eventually replaced by the proper contents of the document, your PDF viewer may not be able to display this type of document.

You can upgrade to the latest version of Adobe Reader for Windows, Mac or Linux.

I do not want to use Adobe Reader is there any way to view the pdf in mupdf?

I was expecting mupdf.exe to properly display the file.

Answer (score 0):

MuPDF under windows or linux is not able to open such PDF with new forms.

If you don't want to use Adobe Reader, you can bypass by using Master PDF Editor (linux, windows…)

Explanation:

> The proprietary and deprecated XFA format for forms is not fully
> supported by Poppler and only supported by Adobe Reader and Master PDF
> Editor.
> (Source: [https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PDF,_PS_and_DjVu#PDF_forms] )